# ViewController not recognizing UITextField

Tags: swift

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw5qq.png

Not sure why it says my UITextField isn't a member. I made sure that the view controller is correctly linked to the correct Swift file.

Comment: please post code as text not images

Answer (score 0):

Move it inside `viewDidLoad`

```
 override func  viewDidLoad () {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let city = self.currentCity.text!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put this variable inside some function. But you put this inside interface of class

```
func whoaStringFunc() {
   let city = currentCity.text!
}
```